# PYQT5 connect a change in QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to find out howto connect a change in QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox in using pyqt5 in python to a method. AFAICS QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox.valueChanged does not have a connect function anymore (as in PYQT4).

I have tried to search for an answer but I just cant seem to find out how to accomplish this...

Anyone who knows?

EDIT1>
Thanks for the reply but I cant see the difference to this:

thanks for your reply, but I cant see the difference to this

```
self.dsbGR = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
self.dsbGR.setDecimals(3)
self.dsbGR.setSingleStep(0.1)
self.dsbGR.setProperty("value", 3.0)
self.dsbGR.setObjectName("dsbGR")
self.dsbGR.valueChanged.connect(myfunction)
```

The last line does not work, there is no `connect`method.

Comment: Could you show how myfunction is implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are not using the [new style of signal and slots connection](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html), in the following example I show its use with the widget QDoubleSpinBox.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())


        self.dsbGR = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.dsbGR.setDecimals(3)
        self.dsbGR.setSingleStep(0.1)
        self.dsbGR.setProperty("value", 3.0)
        self.dsbGR.setObjectName("dsbGR")
        self.dsbGR.valueChanged.connect(self.onValueChanged)
        self.centralWidget().layout().addWidget(self.dsbGR)

    def onValueChanged(self, val):
        print(val)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I cant see the difference to this self.dsbGR = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.dsbGR.setDecimals(3)
        self.dsbGR.setSingleStep(0.1)
        self.dsbGR.setProperty("value", 3.0)
        self.dsbGR.setObjectName("dsbGR")
        self.dsbGR.valueChanged.

Comment: How are you doing the test, you pressed the buttons?

Comment: your snippet works fine but my code (shown above) (inside a class method) does not have the connect..

Comment: Please show more class code, I think the error is elsewhere, please.

Comment: sorry.. it was all about that stupid intellisense that didn't work.. my bad. Sorry to have you use time and energy on this.

Comment: I do not understand you, explain yourself better please

Comment: Sorry... spyder (IDE) intellisense didn't show the method was there (it showed a bunch of other methods though) which lead me to believe that the method didn't exist. so.. I have now learned not to trust that intellisense too much :)